# Why does the master/detail flow template in android studio use multiple activities instead of multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, master-detail

CS student here so please bear with me.

I am trying to wrap my head around the master/detail flow template. I know sometimes the templates are out of touch with the best practices at that time and I am wondering if this is also the case for this template.

Right now the default template includes 2 activities and 1 fragment. 
They are itemListActivity (for android & tablet views), itemDetailActivity (for android view), and itemDetailFragment (for tablet view).

The itemDetailFragment is attached to the itemListActivity if a tablet is detected and if not the the itemDetailActivity is called when an item is clicked.

From what I am gathering from some of the other current template structures, it now seems pretty standard to wrap layouts inside a fragment when it is any code that wont be used in other views. The blank activity template, for example, includes a main activity with (likely) reusable code (toolbar & floating action button) and the rest of the layout is built inside a fragment.

So my question is, now that android now supports nested fragments, if I am making an app with a master/detail flow would it be wise to edit the code so that everything is contained within a nested fragment and place that inside of a main activity.

It would look something like:

```
 Main Activity

   -Toolbar code

   -Include FragmentContainer

FragmentContainer

   -show itemListFragment

   -If tablet sized, show itemDetailFragment (next to itemListFragment)

   -If phone sized, when item is clicked switch view from itemListFragment to itemDetialFragment

itemListFragment

   -include a list of items

itemDetailFragment

   -include the item details
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of an approach like this? Overall is this a good approach or would it be better to stick with default master/detail flow structure? Will I run into any compatibility issues with nested fragments when running on older versions of android? Also, a small question about the default template, why does it use both an itemDetailActivity and an itemDetailFragment when they could simply reuse an itemDetailFragment for both phone and tablet views?

Comment: I fail to see where nested fragments come into play with your description. That's good, as I find nested fragments to be troublesome. Your approach is basically one activity + two fragments instead of two activities + one fragment. There is nothing wrong with your approach. IMHO it makes configuration changes incrementally more difficult. However, it keeps everything within one activity, which is useful given challenges in passing data between activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare i thought it was a nested fragment simply because both the itemListFragment and itemDetailFragment are contained inside the fragmentContainer. Why would I use a fragment container in the first place? Honestly its only because that what seems to match the flow of the other templates (like in my blankActivity example). Perhaps the 2 fragments should just sit right on top of the main activity? I'm too not sure. That's why I'm hoping to get some outside perspective

Comment: I interpreted "fragmentContainer" as being something like a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: What is `FragmentContainer`? Is it a fragment or an activity or something else?

Comment: When I create a Master/Detail app in Android Studio 1.5.1, I see three classes: ItemListActivity, ItemDetailFragment, and ItemDetailActivity. I don't see a class called FragmentContainer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the pseudocode in the code snippet is an alternative layout I was considering implimenting, not the default template. In this particular layout, the fragment container would be a fragment that handles the code for displaying the itemListFragment and itemDetailFragment. Alternatively I could skip the container and add the handle the fragments straight from my main activity. I'm trying to get an idea of what would be the best approach.

Comment: I haven't used nested fragments. I would put the code which manages the fragments in the appropriate event handlers. Often this will be in the activity class.

Comment: I have to chime in.  It seems that google is moving very hard towards the _One Activity Many Fragments_ model.  That their default of one of the most popular layouts doesn't use this implies that not everyone is onboard at Google.